# How to optimize this simple yet slow query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a relatively simple table with several columns, two of them are `expires_at(Date)` and `museum_id(BIGINT, FOREIGN)`. Both indexed, also using a compound index. The table contains around 3 million of rows in it.

Running query as simple as this takes around 90 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT * 
FROM external_users 
WHERE museum_id = 356 
AND ((expires_at > '2022-02-16 07:35:39.818117') OR expires_at IS NULL)
```

Here is the explain analyze output:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on external_users  (cost=2595.76..148500.40 rows=59259 width=1255) (actual time=4901.257..90786.702 rows=94272 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (((museum_id = 356) AND (expires_at > '2022-02-16'::date)) OR ((museum_id = 356) AND (expires_at IS NULL)))
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 391889
  Heap Blocks: exact=34133 lossy=33698
  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=2595.76..2595.76 rows=63728 width=0) (actual time=4671.804..4671.806 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_external_users_on_museum_id_and_expires_at  (cost=0.00..2187.79 rows=54336 width=0) (actual time=1229.564..1229.564 rows=33671 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((museum_id = 356) AND (expires_at > '2022-02-16'::date))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_external_users_on_museum_id_and_expires_at  (cost=0.00..378.34 rows=9391 width=0) (actual time=3442.238..3442.238 rows=64337 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((museum_id = 356) AND (expires_at IS NULL))
Planning Time: 266.470 ms
Execution Time: 90838.777 ms
```

I can't really see anything helpful in the explain/analyze output but that might be related to my lack of experience in such. My peer-reviewer also didn't saw anything interesting in there which makes me think - is there anything i can do in order to help postgres handle queries like that faster or is it just the way it is for tables with over 3M records?

Comment: Just curious: are two separate indexes on museum_id and on expires_at slower than single compound index on both columns?

Comment: not sure but i need both separate and compound as the case above is not the only one used with this table

Comment: If you set expires_at='9999-01-01' instead of null, it will save you one index scan because in this case query will be without OR

Comment: @leftjoin: using `infinity` (or probably `-infinity`) would be better

Comment: @leftjoin you mean during write or during read?

Comment: @mbajur during write  (if instead of nulls in the table were some infinite dates), then your query could be simpler: WHERE museum_id = 356 AND expires_at > '2022-02-16 07:35:39.818117' This is rather common approach BTW

Comment: this sounds super clever and interesting! However, if i understand it well, skipping this index call reduces runtime a lot but query still takes around 15s which is sadly unacceptable :(

Comment: How big is the table in MB?  Is it very bloated?  What is your work_mem?

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing, then run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and show that.

Comment: @jjanes it's 1.89GB and work_mem is 4MB

Comment: Visiting nearly 68000 blocks (exact=34133 lossy=33698) is over 1/4 of the table.  Visiting that much table is going to take a long time just due to the IO involved., unless you can keep it all cached in RAM.

Comment: How many rows have `museum_id = 356`?

Answer (score 0):

I will explain to you some rules, ways to optimize this query.

1 - When you use `OR` command on the where conditions, then DB can not use indexes.  Recommended using union all. Example:

```
select * 
from external_users 
where museum_id = 356 
and expires_at > '2022-02-16 07:35:39.818117'
    union all 
select * 
from external_users 
where museum_id = 356 
and expires_at is null
```

2 - Your `expires_at` field may be a timestamp type. But, `date` types are faster than `timestamp` types. Because in `timestamp` types stored hours, minutes, seconds. Also, indexing size `timestamp` types will be greater than `date` type indexing size. If you need to store full `datetime`, then you can use casting types. For the best performance you must create a function-based index (on PostgreSQL this is called expression index), but not a standard index.

```
select * 
from external_users 
where museum_id = 356 
and expires_at::date > '2022-02-16'
    union all 
select * 
from external_users 
where museum_id = 356 
and expires_at is NULL 
/* 
We must cast `expires_at` field type to date type during creating the indexing process. Because in our query we use casting this type, so we must create an index via casting data.
*/
create index external_users_expires_at_idx 
ON external_users USING btree ((expires_at::date));
```

3 - In where conditions if you are using always two, three fields samely, recommended creating one index for these fields, but not separately. In your query maybe always use `museum_id` and  `expires_at` fields. Create index sample code:

```
create index external_users_full_index on external_users  using btree (museum_id, (expires_at ::date));
```

The most important of all these ways is the first rule, so not using `OR` command.